# horizontal scrolling carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Never good to start off with an apology but please allow me to apologise for the terrible title of this post and also apologise for asking a question which has no doubt been asked countless times before. However, as I couldn't think of an appropriate title for this post you can image how well my searching went.

I'm looking to replicate the scrolling effect on the [fitbit website](https://www.fitbit.com/uk/charge) where the section starts with "Get energized, take charge."

I have a rough grasp of what is happening here but don't have the smarts to piece it all together.

- User scrolls page to this div.
- JS calculates scroll position of this div and sets a class on the parent div which changes its state to fixed.
- Child divs are now scrollable due to the change of state.
- JS knows position of last child div, and when its at the top of the parent div, it removes class from parent and allows rest of the page to scroll normally once again.

I think I can calculate the second bullet point using something like

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

And I can toggle the class on the parent easily enough. What I'm struggling to grasp is how the JS knows that the last child div has been scrolled and then organising that within the function to remove the class from the parent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note, I'm already using jcarousel on this project and if I could reuse existing code that would be great but I don't even know if this plugin can handle what I'm looking for.

Comment: Probably you won't be able to use jcarousel

For this kind of stuffs I use this library: [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), demo [here](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)